# Mysql triggers with multiple values

Tags: mysql, triggers

How can i do the same with username value in one trigger?

Thanks

```
DELIMITER //
  CREATE TRIGGER notnullnameandsurname BEFORE INSERT ON guests FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
  IF new.name = "" then
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000';
  END IF;
  END //
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `or`?

```
DELIMITER //
  CREATE TRIGGER notnullnameandsurname BEFORE INSERT ON guests FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
  IF new.name = '' or new.username = '' then
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000';
  END IF;
  END //
```